# How to use printf() method with long values in Java?

Tags: java, printf, long-integer

I remember that I did this in C but I couldn’t get it work in Java.

How to print long values with printf() method in Java?

I tried with below code what I actually need is to print the long value in hexadecimal way like below

long l = 32L -----> 0000000000000022

If I use %d then it prints integer value which I don’t want...

```
class TestPrintf() 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    long l = 100L;

    System.out.printf(“%l”+l); // Error unknown format exception
    System.out.printf(“%d”+l); // Prints 100
    System.out.printf(“%f”+l); // Unknown illegal format conversion float != java.lang.long
    }
}
```

Comment: And how doesn't %d fit you exactly? Do you expect a final `L` or something?

Comment: The call should be `System.out.printf("%d", l);`. See [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

Comment: if remember long value in C language print something like 0x00000000DEADBEEF(not exactly somewhat similar) ....I am expecting this answer

Comment: %x or %X is what you're after then.

Comment: hexadecimal value might be 'x'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put the actual argument to print as the next argument of a `printf()` methods. Concatenating will not work.

```
System.out.printf("%d%n", 123);             // for ints and longs
System.out.printf("%d%n", 12345L);          // for ints and longs
System.out.printf("%f%n", (double) 12345L); // for floating point numbers
```

Full documentation in `java.util.Formatter`

Comment: It doesn’t work with java I want hexdecimal value for long :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want a 16-character zero-padded string, with `A-F` in uppercase, prefixed by `0x`, you should use:

```
System.out.printf("0x%016X", l);
```

Comment: BTW, it really helps people trying to help you if you state exactly what you're looking for *in your question*. The other answers here are entirely valid for what you asked initially; this answer is based on information provided in a much later comment.